# How do I create an inner class that inherits from an outside class that has two trailing underscores ("__")?

Tags: python, python-3.x, class, inheritance

Put differently, I want to create the class `Thing` that exists inside of `Some_Category`. I also want the `Thing` class to inherit from `__Thing_Abstract`, which exists outside of the local scope of `Some_Category`. I am not sure as to how I should go about doing this.

```
class __Thing_Abstract:
    def __init__(self,var):
        self.var=var


class Some_Category:
    class Thing(__Thing_Abstract):
        def printVar(self): print(self.var)
    
        def getType(self): return type(self.var)
```

I do understand that the "two trailing underscores" writing convention (`__`) does not make a Python class private. For example, if I were to create the class `A_Class` with an `__init__` method that instantiates a variable `__data` and then attempt to access it, I would write something like this: `_A_Class__data`.

```
class A_Class:
    def __init__(self):
        self.__data="Data"

print(A_Class()._A_Class__data)
```

This example returns `Data`.

I assumed that in the first example, Python would look in the global scope first when trying to inherit from `__Thing_Abstract`, similarly when referencing another class inside some method.

```
class A_Class1:
    def __init__(self,data):
        self.data=data


class A_Class2:
    def method(data):
        print(A_Class1(data).data)


A_Class2.method("Random Data")
```

This example "works fine" and prints `Random Data`.

When I run the first example, however, it returns the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/user/test.py", line 6, in <module>
    class Some_Category:
  File "/home/user/test.py", line 7, in Some_Category
    class Thing(__Thing_Abstract):
NameError: name '_Some_Category__Thing_Abstract' is not defined
```

I am wondering how I would go about solving this problem.

Comment: Is there a particular reason you want to use double leading underscores *and* nested classes in this code? Neither of those are normally particularly useful things, and your trouble comes exclusively from combining them.

Comment: Jusr remove all those leading double underscores.

Comment: I usually only create nested classes when they edit/change the contents of the main class. I put them together to clarify that they are related.  The question above is not a very good example of that. Also, I totally acknowledge and respect that nested classes are generally considered a bad practice.I usually only use double underscores because they remind me that the class is not a main class, but probably an abstract one. I just always assumed that using two underscores in the name would keep it accessible to everything in the file because it is created in the global scope.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By setting the class `__Thing_Abstract` as class attribute of `Some_Category`

```
class __Thing_Abstract:
    def __init__(self,var):
        self.var=var


class Thing(__Thing_Abstract):
    def __init__(self, var):
        super().__init__(var)

    def printVar(self): print(self.var)

    def getType(self): return type(self.var)


class Some_Category:
    Thing = Thing


print(Some_Category.Thing.__name__)
#Thing
print(Some_Category.Thing.__bases__[0].__name__)
#__Thing_Abstract
print(Some_Category.Thing(9).printVar)
#<bound method Thing.printVar of <__main__.Thing object at 0x7fc0cd238fa0>>
```

Alternatively, to bypass the scoping problem, you can use [`globals()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#globals)

```
class __Thing_Abstract:
    def __init__(self,var):
        self.var=var


class Some_Category:
    class Thing(globals()['__Thing_Abstract']):
        def printVar(self): print(self.var)

        def getType(self): return type(self.var)
```

... and at this point you should ask yourself if keeping tracks of all the `__`-classes with a dictionaries would be better: `my__cls = {`__Thing_Abstract`: __Thing_Abstract, ...}`

Hint: With decorators you could achieve this in a more elegant way... but there are many possibilities

[From the comment] Here a basic example to make a custom dictionary to keep track of the `__`-classes. Note that the `my_cls` and `my__cls_updater` should be defined before the `__`-classes.

```
my__cls = {} # keep track of all __-classes

def my__cls_updater(cls):
    if not cls.__name__.startswith('__'):
        print('...hey that s not a __-class!')
        return cls

    my__cls.update({cls.__name__: cls}) # update thge global dictionary
    return cls


@my__cls_updater # <-- each __-class should be preceed by the decorator call
class __Thing_Abstract:
    def __init__(self,var):
        self.var=var


class Some_Category:
    class Thing(my__cls['__Thing_Abstract']):
        def printVar(self): print(self.var)

        def getType(self): return type(self.var)
```

"Elegance" is a bit subjective but hope at least useful.